# left join causing duplicates rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query that successfully grabs the unique products from my products table and displays them. I am trying to add an icon table into the mix, where some products can have several icons. the problem is I am trying to only use joins, and when a product has 2 icons for instance, I will get 2 rows selected for that 1 product.

Here is my sql:

```
    SELECT p.products_image, 
           pd.products_name, 
           p.products_id, 
           p.products_model, 
           p.manufacturers_id, 
           p.products_price, 
           p2i.icons_id, 
           p.products_tax_class_id, 
           IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS 
           specials_new_products_price, 
           IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS 
           final_price 
    FROM   products p 
           LEFT JOIN manufacturers m 
                  ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
           LEFT JOIN specials s 
                  ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN products_to_categories p2c 
                  ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN products_description pd 
                  ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
           LEFT JOIN products_to_icon p2i 
                  ON p.products_id = p2i.products_id 
    WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
           AND pd.language_id = '1' 
           AND p2c.categories_id = '36'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end.
If you still want all the icon ids, you can combine with `group_concat`

E.g.:

```
SELECT p.products_image, 
       pd.products_name, 
       p.products_id, 
       group_concat(p2i.icons_id separator ",") as icons_ids
       (...)
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p2c.categories_id = '36'
GROUP BY p.products_id
```

Comment: But then I am only selecting the 1 icon in the selection no? At least when I do that query in phpmyadming I am only getting 2 rows (both products) and only seeing 1 icon per row.. I think I need to rethink this actually.. Maybe when displaying only display unique? I'm not sure what to do..